# i want magento cart to have 0 items default when you visit the website

Tags: magento-enterprise

On my website header I have a shopping cart icon with a badge that display the number of the items in the cart. When you enter in the website, it should display 0, as you have no item in the cart. However the badge is empty until you add a item in the cart. But if you later remove all items than it does display 0.

i want the cart to have 0 items when you visit the website

Comment: can you post your cart file code here if possible ??

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this so when you don't have any item in your cart it will display 0.

```
<?php $_cartQty = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount(); ?>

<?php echo '<span class="summary-qty">' . ($_cartQty ? $_cartQty : 0) . '</span>' ?>
```